# iOS/iPadOS: Shortcuts from unknown source - inspect what it does for real

Tags: ios

I'm trying to teach iPhone/iPad to import a calendar event from `*.ics` file (by default it's possible only when `*.ics` is opened from and only from Mail app).

I found there is a shortcut called [ICS To Calendar](https://routinehub.co/shortcut/7005/) which does exactly what I need. But [routinehub.co](https://routinehub.co) is not one of official trusted sources.

I'd  like to examine what does this shortcut in real before installing it. What I know about shortcuts is that they are basically XML files with routine blocks there.

Is possible to download it from different device and open in text editor to see what it does? Or is there some other way?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of downloading it on a different device and try to understand the xml-code, you can just download it on your iPad, and then it will open in the shortcuts app without directly being installed or integrated in any way. Instead you will be shown a complete editable copy of the given shortcut like if you did it yourself, and there you can look into every executed part of it.

---

Just for the record, trusting unknown shortcuts can be really dangerous, I would recommend to send the file to your own email and open it from there. Then you can be sure that it is installed properly and nothing bad happens.